# Have I interpretted this "semantic web primer for object oriented developers" correctly?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, rdfs

[This document](https://www.w3.org/TR/sw-oosd-primer/) states that "Therefore, pointing ack(sic) to the above example, if something has a price, then it can be handled as an instance of Product, even if it partakes in other declarations (or triples) "

Do a word search to find the reference.

Basically, they are saying that the domain of the property "hasPrice" is "Product". This means that all products could have a price (makes sense so far), but it also means that anything that has the property "hasPrice" can be treated as a "Product". This seems a bit loose to me. Speaking in OOP terms, surely they don't mean that anything with the property "hasPrice" implements the "Product" interface, do they? That would be madness!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you state that the domain of `hasPrice` is `Product`, both RDF and OWL will infer that anything that has a `hasPrice` property is of type `Product`. So in that regard your understanding is correct. Note that if `hasPrice` is defined without a domain, the reasoner will not make this inference.

In an ontology, if you have a `Service` that also has a `hasPrice` property, it will infer that it is a `Product`. You will get an inconsistency in your ontology if you state that `Service` is disjoint from `Product`.

A way around it is to introduce a class in your ontology for representing the domain, say `HasPriceDomain` which is the union of all domain of your `hasPrice` property. This will cause anything with a `hasPrice` property to be inferred to be of type `HasPriceDomain`.

```
DataProperty: hasPrice
    Domain: HasPriceDomain    
    Range: xsd:double

Class: HasPriceDomain
    EquivalentTo: Product or Service

Class: Product
    SubClassOf: hasPrice some xsd:double
    DisjointWith: Service

Class: Service
    SubClassOf: hasPrice some xsd:double
    DisjointWith: Product
```

From an OOP perspective it is best to think of OOP classes as RDF/OWL classes and OOP instances of classes as RDF/OWL individuals.

In OOP interfaces usually specify behaviour (i.e. methods), which cannot trivially be translated to RDF/OWL. Starting out with RDF/OWL it is probably best to focus on classes only.

For detailed information on translating OOP to OWL, see https://henrietteharmse.com/uml-vs-owl/. For detail regarding the translation of methods, see Chapter 5 of https://henrietteharmse.files.wordpress.com/2017/09/scenariotestingusingowl_v0-1-7-final.pdf.

Comment: So lets come up with something else, that we wouldn't naturally think of as a product, but is equally generic, (as I write this I find that I am having trouble coming up with something real so...) lets call it abc. Does the fact that abc exists, has a price, and isn't naturally thought of as a product, is this an indication that our object model (ontology?) is inconsistent and needs something more basic than either product or abc to represent things that have prices?

Comment: No, not necessarily. As I said, interfaces don't translate easily to ontologies.

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'non necessarily'? Can you think of a situation similar to the above, where 'abc' is not thought of as a 'product' but has a price, yet somehow having a reasoner inferring that things that are of class 'abc' are also of class 'product' is acceptable?

Comment: @ChechyLevas you're thinking about this the wrong way around. The very fact that you've given it a price means that _by definition_, it's a product. If 'abc' is not a product, you shouldn't be giving it a price, or alternatively, if it turns out that there are in fact things in your universe that have prices but are not products, you shouldn't have the domain of your property set to Product.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra isn’t that what I suggested in my first comment?

Comment: _scrolls up_ why, so it is, yes. I misunderstood your second comment. I think the confusion comes from your use of the term 'inconsistent', which has a specific meaning in logic and ontology. The model is not inconsistent (in the logical sense), it merely doesn't correspond with a real world interpretation.